# Image-alternative for "Link to" anchor

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I try to create simple functionality: user is clicking on image and he is redirecting to another page. From now I now that I can use "Link to" but it applies to inline elements. What if I need to use graphic element (picture/icon) instead? I've used the link also to it but it needs to another styling and I'm not quite sure if it is a good practice  to use "Link to" for pictures ? It works fine but I would be grateful for answer because of my doubts.

```
<div className="wrapper"><Link to='/bag'><img id="shop" src={shopping_bag} /></Link>
                  <h6 id="sum">{this.state.total}</h6>
    </div>
```

Comment: Post sample code. I am not too sure what you are asking.

Comment: As @Dadsquatch said, maybe provide a running example on https://codesandbox.io or something similar. Generally speaking it is ok to add other components to `Link` as children.

Comment: @Jan P so it is not a bad practice to use it on image ? How to overide text-decoration:none on :active in css in this case (in relation with Link component) ?

Comment: You can style `Link` just as every other react component.